# Möbius transformation mapping $\mathfrak{J}(z)>0$ to itself

Tags: proof-explanation, mobius-transformation

I got following proof for "Search for all Möbius transformations that map the upper half plane to itself bijectively"

---

Proof:

Define
\begin{align*}
&M(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d} \\
&M(0) = \frac{b}{d}\in \mathbb{R}_{\infty} \\
&M(\infty) = \frac{a}{c}\in \mathbb{R}_{\infty} \\
&M^{-1}(0) = -\frac{b}{a}\in \mathbb{R}_{\infty} \\
&M^{-1}(\infty) = -\frac{a}{c}\in \mathbb{R}_{\infty}
\end{align*}

Then by $$M(i) = \frac{ai+b}{ci+d}= \frac{(ad-bc)i+(ac+bd)}{c^2+d^2}$$
we see that $\Im(M(i)) > 0 \Rightarrow ad-bc >0$

So, $$M(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}, \quad a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}, \quad ad-bc=1$$
and the set of Möbius transformations is
$$Aut(\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid \Im z >0\})= \{\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}\mid \det(...)=1\}/\{\pm id\}$$

---

If I understand correctly we first show that we can map the real axis to itself? That's where we define the special cases for $0, \infty$.

Then check with $M(i)$ what other constraints we need s.t. $M(i)$ actually maps to the upper half plane. We see that $ad-bc>0$.

But after that I don't understand why $ad-bc=1$ and why we can so easily follow that $a,b,c,d$ are real. They could also all be complex?

Can someone help me understand?

Comment: @JeanMarie almost. I saw in the link you provided that $ad-bc>0$ is sufficient. So $\det(...)>0$ should be written instead of $\det(...)=1$?

Comment: That's right...